# Adding Javascript on the fly

Tags: javascript

I got a question in theory... I'm currently at work and can't try it..

If I have the following code :

```
stuff = '<button onclick="alert(' + "'Test');" + 'my Button</button>';
$("container").html(stuff);
```

When I click on my new button, will my script work? And will my button be added?

I didn't get any result on JsFiddle...

Comment: your selector "container" is probably wrong, to start with. Please link to the fiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: I would consider binding the event in JavaScript, in addition to fixing your tag: `$("container").replaceAll($("<button>my Button</button>").click(function () { alert("Test"); }));`

Comment: @bfavaretto The quotes look fine. That's the reason he alternates single and double quotes, presumably because he doesn't know how to backslash-escape them.  The problem is actually the missing `>`.

Comment: @cdhowie Agree on the binding via JS, but I would do `var $('<button>my button</button>').appendTo('container').click(function () { alert('Test'); }));`. IIRC `replaceAll` puts the original selector into the functions argument.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus That's why `replaceAll()` wraps the *entire* subexpression.  Unwrap my code and indent it in an editor and you will see.

Comment: @cdhowie You're partially correct, but it's also missing a double quote before `>` to close the attribute.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, that's true too. But it's not a problem due to incorrect escaping.  :)  Of course, there is *weird* escaping, but not *incorrect* escaping.

Comment: @cdhowie I meant you had the replaceAll syntax backwards - see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GsD2/1/) and [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/). You should be calling `replaceAll` on the button, passing the container as the argument. It replaces all instances of the argument with the origin.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus I see.  In that case, `replaceAll()` isn't the right function to use in this context, no matter how you invoke it.  It looks like `.empty().appendTo(...)` is the correct replacement.

Comment: Wow! thank for all the reply! I admit that the I've miss the '#' for the container and the '>' on the button. And yes, I don't know how to escape string in Java! I'm new to the process! I think I'll look it up so I have nicer code.

Comment: @DanielBerthiaume This is JavaScript, not Java.  They are completely different languages with almost *nothing* in common, besides similar-looking syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you fix the selector "container" and the unclosed tag, it should work.

But that's not how you bind events properly using jQuery.

You should do this :

```
$("#container").empty().append(
    $('<button>my Button</button>').click(function(){ alert("Test") })
);
```

Comment: After reading the docs, I don't think replaceAll nor replaceWith does the right thing.  I was looking for a method that replaces all child elements with the elements in the supplied query.  I think the only way to do that is `$("#container").empty().appendTo(...)`.  I believe this is what we want in this case to replace `.html(...)`.

Comment: And good call on editing to use `append()` instead of `appendTo()`, as I mistakenly said.  After looking at jQuery docs all day you get these methods confused with each other...

Answer (score 2):

It would work if you closed the opening button tag correctly

```
stuff = '<button onclick="alert(' + "'Test');" + '">my Button</button>';
$("container").html(stuff);                       ^^
```

Also as pointed out in a comment your selector for container is probably wrong.

Most likely you want one of these 2 depending on if container is a class or id:

```
$(".container").html(stuff);
$("#container").html(stuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

That would work, but you forgot to close your button tag.

```
stuff = '<button onclick="alert(\'Test\');">my Button</button>';
$("container").html(stuff);
```